# How to make an android x86 virtualbox machine?

Tags: virtualbox, hardware, android

I have been trying to install an android x86 system using virtualbox, using the isos , but it only gives a black screen.

It is selected the Linux 2.6 32bits, and from the general configuration it is deselected the floppy option only.

Boot, then select the install, select the drive, install, sync drives and at reboot it starts but does not show anything at all, Im guessing its a video driver issue (it has been tested with vboxvga,vmsvga and vboxsvga options).

Comment: Linux 2.6 is extremely old. Which android x86 are you using?

Comment: Later releases ftom 7 onwards.

Comment: the latest release is Android 11. And if you're using https://www.android-x86.org/ then it's also at version 10. Even Android 7 can't run on Linux 2.6